# How to access Cython struct in Python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, cython, ctypes

I have the following Python modules:
temp1.py

```
import ctypes as c

class datapoints(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c.c_int16),
                ('y', c.c_int16),
                ('z', c.c_int16)]
```

temp2.py

```
import temp1

data = bytearray(b'\x05\x00\x0B\x02\x10\x02')

print(data)

a = temp1.datapoints.from_buffer(data)

for i in a._fields_:
    print(i[0], getattr(a, i[0]))

a.x = 7
a.y = 2
a.z = 8

print(data)

for i in a._fields_:
    print(i[0], getattr(a, i[0]))
```

Running temp2.py outputs:

```
bytearray(b'\x05\x00\x0b\x02\x10\x02')
x 5
y 523
z 528
bytearray(b'\x07\x00\x02\x00\x08\x00')
x 7
y 2
z 8
```

The following module attempts to replicate temp1.py in Cython.
speed1.pyx

```
cdef struct datapoints:
    int x
    int y
    int z
```

The following module attempts to import speed1.pyx and use the struct to no avail.
temp3.py

```
import speed1

data = bytearray(b'\x05\x00\x0B\x45\x10\x02')

a = speed1.datapoints(data)
```

I get the following errors:

```
a = speed1.datapoints(data)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'speed1' has no attribute 'datapoints'
```

I can't find anything online on how to use Cython structs. I want to use Cython structs to speed up my codes that rely heavily on ctypes.Structures. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use structs in Cython then you have to use them *from within Cython*, they aren't something you can import into Python. The conversion from a bytearray isn't easily defined either (although you could probably do it with casts from within Cython). You may find ctypes fits what you're trying to do better